# Drag list item to itemeditor

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I work with AIR.

I have to window, one with list ( a glossary) and another with datagrid and editable cells.
The goal is to drag item on list and drop it on cursor position on itemEditor (datagrid).
I don't know how to do that.

This below the code I use to do the same action not in the datagrid but on a textarea what is on the same datagrid window.

// On 1st window (glossary)

```
<s:List dataProvider="{DP_GlossList2}" id="list2"
                            labelField="glNom"
                            dragEnabled="true"
                            dropEnabled="true"
                            dragMoveEnabled="true"
                            click="list2_clickHandler(event)"
                            height="60%" width="100%"/>
```

// on second window : textarea and datagrid

// drag drop

```
 protected function retTTAfaire_dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void
        {
            retTTAfaire.text = retTTAfaire.text.substring(0,retTTAfaire.selectionAnchorPosition)+ " "+event.dragSource.dataForFormat("itemsByIndex")[0].glNom+
                " "+retTTAfaire.text.substring(retTTAfaire.selectionAnchorPosition+1);
        }

        protected function retTTAfaire_dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void
        {
            DragManager.acceptDragDrop(spark.components.TextArea(event.target));

        }
```

Please, help me.
Thanks

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c0a.html

Comment: Google first, guess second, stack overflow third.  Please don't flood the questions queue with everything you don't know, I could be here all day posting everything I don't know.  Good questions here include some level of effort and/or an error that someone else may encounter and benefit from having the solution here.  It's not my intention to push you away but you must show some effort if I'm going to put in the time to help you.  Maybe you are trying, but you're not showing it in your posts, link to things you've tried post code you've tried.

Comment: Despite your opinion, I search a lot before post question. For my problem, I found how to drad drop between to list but not with add item.label at the end of datagrid itemEditor!

Comment: Just saying you should show some code (it's difficult to guess where you've gone wrong if you don't show where you've gone).  Also, I like it when people include the specific versions they're using.  I have a lot of the Flex SDKs so if someone gives me a version and some code I can just copy paste in a test project and get them a tested answer.  Without either of those pieces of information I mostly have to go off of experience (which doesn't always pan out between versions, or ability to recollect) or attempting to build whatever you're doing.  I answered one of your questions it had code :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer, but one area to investigate is using the `getObjectsUnderPoint()` method (from DisplayObjectContainer). Using a point - from the local coordinate system from the Drag/Mouse event. This will get you looking at the "right" branch of the display tree.

I think your hard part to figure out is knowing exactly which element you want to interact with - in this case the item editor. When iterating your *suspect list*, you'll want to compare it against an interface that the ItemEditor (`IGridItemRenderer`) is known to have but not other objects.

Also depending on what reference the mouseX/mouseY coordinates lie in, you'll most likely need to convert it to the same coordinate system that the item editor is in - in this case Editors are handled by the PopupManager (or the SystemManager) - or should be if the Flex SDK team followed the same paradigm with spark as they did with halo - but I haven't verified this.

I can't tell from the wording of your question, but if you are trying to allow items to be placed after the item editor is opened - this will get very difficult because of focus management.